# html / css menu hitbox

Tags: html, css, menu

I wrote a code using different internet source and I ran into a problem every object that's in the bottom of the menu parts cannot be interacted the menu interferes everything below him where the dropdown falls . the hitbox of the menu seems to included the dropdown even when its not shown

```css
body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 23px;
    }
    #nav {
        background-color:1a1a1a;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }
    #nav_wrapper {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: right;
    }
    #nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        min-width: 200px;
    }
    #nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #nav ul li:hover {
        background-color: #333;
    }
    #nav ul li a, visited {
        color: #CCC;
        display: block;
        padding: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #nav ul li:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }
    #nav ul ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #333;
        border: 0px solid #222;
        border-top: 0;
        margin-left: -5px;
    }
    #nav ul ul li {
        display: block;
    }
    #nav ul ul li a:hover {
        color: #699;
    }
    .left-to-right {
        text-align: left;
    }
```

```html
    <body  dir-"rtl"><div id="nav">
    
        <div id="nav_wrapper">
    <div>
            <ul <ul  dir="RTL">
    
                <li> <a href="#">תרמילים</a>
    
                    <ul class="left-to-right">
    <!--  <li class="backpacks" id="firstlight-20l"> <a href="/products/firstlight-20l"> FirstLight 20L</a> </li>
    
                            <li class="backpacks" id="firstlight-30l"> <a href="/products/firstlight-30l"> FirstLight 30L</a> </li>
    
                            <li class="backpacks" id="firstlight-40l"> <a href="/products/firstlight-40l"> FirstLight 40L</a> </li>-->
    
                            <li class="backpacks"> <a href="/products/rotation180-professional-Deluxe"> rotation180° Professional 38L Deluxe</a> </li>
    
                            <li class="backpacks"> <a href="/products/rotation180-horizon"> rotation180° Horizon 34L</a> </li>
    
                            <li class="backpacks"> <a href="/products/rotation180-panorama"> rotation180° Panorama 22L</a> </li>
    
    <!--                        <li class="backpacks" id="rotation180-travel-away"> <a href="/products/rotation180-travel-away"> rotation180° Travel Away 22L</a> </li>-->
    
                            <li class="backpacks" id="rotation180-trail"> <a href="/products/rotation180-trail"> rotation180° Trail 16L</a> </li>
    
                          </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">תיקי מצלמות ספורט</a>
    
                    <ul class="left-to-right">
                        <li><a href="#">GP 1 kit case</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">GP 2 kit case</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">אביזרים</a>
    
                    <ul class="left-to-right">
                        <li><a href="#">r180º Panorama/Horizon Photo Insert</a>
                        </li>
    
                    </ul>
                </li>
    
            </ul>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Help will be appreciated

edit:
the menu is working but everything below him in the area where the dropdown fals dosent

Comment: Are you saying that the links in the menu are not working?

Comment: your problem is not clear. please elaborate.

Comment: The menu is working for me.

Comment: seems like he has something behind his menu which is not working. but still require more info to work upon.

Comment: "everything below him in the area where the dropdown fals dosent" Put some of that content in there so we can see what happens. Appending my own text at the end of body doesn't seem to cause the issue described.